# JUnit assert by partial string

Tags: junit5

I need to write a junit for a method which return below XmlString and I need to assert it. In the below XML String `boLastChangedDatetime` will always have the timestamp. How do I assert this String ignoring the tag `boLastChangedDatetime`?

```
<Msg><firstName>Hello</firstName><boLastChangedDatetime>2019-07-29T14:46:56.230Z</boLastChangedDatetime><lastName>World</lastName><root></Msg>
```

for ex: instead of `2019-07-29T14:46:56.230Z` I would require to give some wildcard

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me

```
public static boolean match(String text, String pattern)
{
  return text.matches(pattern.replace("?", ".?").replace("*", ".*?"));
}


Assert.assertTrue(match("HELLO WORLD", "<Msg><firstName>Hello</firstName><boLastChangedDatetime>*</boLastChangedDatetime><lastName>World</lastName><root></Msg>
"));
```

Refrence 
http://blog.janjonas.net/2012-03-06/java-test-string-match-wildcard-expression